# Как указать путь к DLL в VS19

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, link, visual-studio-2019

Где/как в настройках VS19 указать путь к DLL?

У меня есть чужой Solution состоящие из 13 Проектов. 12 из которых создают сложно взаимосвязанные DLL для работы 13 проекта который создает EXE. С созданием 12 DLL/LIB я разобрался, они все видят друг друга и компилируются, но 13 проект который состоит всего из пары строк в которых происходит вызов функций одной из уже существующих DLL не может ее найти на стадии линковки, то есть скорей всего он ее "не видит".

> Ошибка    LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl MBuildSSOMIV_hs(double,double &,double &,double &,double &,double &,char *)" (_*imp*?MBuildSSOMIV_hs@@YAHNAEAN0000PEAD@Z).  Fly C:\Users\Илья\source\repos\Fly\Fly\Fly.obj  1

Как ему ее указать?
Как прописать путь?
Где прописать путь?

Comment: На этапе линковки он не должен знать про dll, ему нужна статическая библиотека(.lib), подключаешь её в настройках, а потом чтобы запустить программу, dll нужно положить рядом с exe

Answer (score 1):

Вам в настройках проекта нужно убедиться, что в Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies указаны все необходимые lib файлы. А в Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories пути к этим файлам, если сами файлы указаны без путей